# How to pause and restart a AxShockwaveFlash control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, flash, axshockwaveflash

I have a AxShockwaveFlash control in a windows forms user control.
This is on my wpf user control inside a WindowsFormsHost.

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <fC:FlashControl x:Name="flashControl"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

To start the movie I call:

```
axShockwaveFlash.Movie = "C:\flashMovie.flv"
```

But calling methods on the AxShockwaveFlash control that is inside the FlashControl such as:

`axShockwaveFlash.Play();
axShockwaveFlash.Stop();
axShockwaveFlash.StopPlay();
axShockwaveFlash.FrameNum = 0;`

Don't do anything.

Comment: Can you point to the documentation that makes you think that the movie has these particular methods and properties? They don't look right. For one thing, inside Flash, play() and stop() are always lowercase. What do you expect StopPlay() to do?

Comment: This is another problem, can't seem to find any documentation for it. All I have to go on is the method names, you would think calling Stop would stop the movie and play would play the movie, perhaps StopPlay would toggle the Playing state? These are just the methods that are available on the AxShockwaveFlash object and most of them do nothing at all.

Comment: It may be that the swf you've embedded has nested clips, which would not be stopped or played by addressing the entire document.